# Is there a novel that incorporates all of the theories included in Jacques Derrida's 'Seven Missiles, Seven Missives'?

Tags: postmodernism

Jacques Derrida came up with some theories about postmodern apocalypses in his Seven Missiles, Seven Missives. I'm looking for a novel that incorporates most of that, if not all.

Comment: Is there any chance you could maybe unpack what you are looking for a little here? Just in passing, reference requests are usually used here for finding relevant philosophical texts, not necessarily things like novels

Comment: I'm trying to find a novel that applies Jacques Derrida's theories on postmodern apocalypse. One of which i.e. goes like this, Derrida mentions that literature will be one of the few forms of texts that will meet an irreversible destruction after the postmodern apocalypse because its existence solely depends on archiving. Which is why the idea of apocalypse is widly injected to it. I need to approve his theories with a novel written by a known writer. I've managed to find Metro 2033 which supports his theories to some extent, but I'm wondering if there are more suitable choices out there.